# Order sql query results by the first not null column

Tags: sqlite

I want to order the results of my query by one column, or in case it's null, by a second one.

In MSSQL I usually solve this problem by using the COEALSCE function, so, I write `ORDER BY COALESCE(Col1,Col2)`.

But, although COALESCE function also exists in SqlLite it seems I can't call it from the 'order by' part of my query

Do you have any idea about how I can sort my results?

***FIX***

COALESCE(Col1,Col2) works with 'simple' queries, What I really want is order the results from a UNION query.

```
CREATE TABLE FOO
(
    int ID,
    Date1 text,
    Date2 text
)
insert into foo values(1,null,'2021-11-12T009:30:00');
insert into foo values(2,'2021-11-12T008:30:00',null);

-- THIS WORKS!
select * from FOO order by coalesce(Date1,Date2)
 
-- THIS FAILS :(
select * from foo where Date1 = '2021-11-12T008:30:00'
union all
select * from foo where Date2 = '2021-11-12T009:30:00'
order by coalesce(Date1,Date2)
```

Comment: Please include a) the exact error and b) the full query.

Comment: This *should* work. Maybe a bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include the COALESCE in the SELECT clause and order by that. I.E.:

```
select COALESCE(Date1,Date2) oby,* from foo where Date1 = '2021-11-12T008:30:00'
union all
select COALESCE(Date1,Date2),* from foo where Date2 = '2021-11-12T009:30:00'
order by oby
```

Answer (score 1):

Put the `UNION` in a derived table.

```
SELECT *
       FROM (SELECT *
                    FROM foo
                    WHERE date1 = '2021-11-12T008:30:00'
             UNION ALL
             SELECT *
                    FROM foo
                    WHERE date2 = '2021-11-12T009:30:00') x
       ORDER BY coalesce(date1,
                         date2);
```